# angular 2-way binding in table cell

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to render a table with every row cell in the ith (say 2nd) column being a select dropdown. And by default the selected value in that select dropdown to be the value of the second column in the jth row from the array of objects that is populating my table. This is my html

```
<tr *ngFor = 'let row of tableData'>
    <td>{{row.user_id}}</td>
    <td> 
        <select [(ngModel)]="row.auditor_id" (ngModelChange)="someFuncLaterDefined($event)">
            <option *ngFor = 'let a of auditors' [ngValue]="a.id">{{a.name}}</option> 
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my ts file/ the code inside ngOnInit:

```
this.nodeapiservice.getAllAuditors().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.auditors = data; 
}) 
this.nodeapiservice.getAllUsers().subscribe(
  data => {
      this.tableData = data;  
});
```

The problem is the select box is populating with empty as value being shown by default. When I click on it I am able to get the correct list of values to select from. And also, even then, after I select a value and close it, when I click on it to make the dropdown appear again the selected value is always option 1. The data fetch is completely correct -- giving me the right data in the right format -- just fyi. 
All answers suggest to use ngModel for 2-way data binding. I am already using that. What do I need to change to do these two?

Comment: can u recreate similar issue on stackBlitz and share ?

Comment: I think i can achieve what you are trying to do, have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqk7lv

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do what I wanted. I will have a look at your solution as soon as I am free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `row.auditor_id` after you retrieve the data from your API.

```
ngOnInit() {
  Observable.combineLatest(
    this.nodeapiservice.getAllAuditors(),
    this.nodeapiservice.getAllUsers()
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    [this.tableData, this.auditors] = data;
    this.tableData.forEach((row, i) => {
      let j = i+1;
      if (j == this.auditors.length) {
        j = 0;
      }
      row.auditor_id = this.auditors[j].id;
    });
  });
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgavwk